# Pause programmatically on iOS device using PhoneGap application

Tags: ios, cordova, events, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

I am developing a PhoneGap application for multiple platforms. I want to programmatically pause application in some cases (when opening PDF file for example onPause is fired in android device but not on an iOS device).

Comment: onPause fires when you open another activity or another app in Android. In iOS you can have viewWillDisappear, when you present a new ViewController.

Comment: perfect! but i don't have many informations about ViewController and how to integrate it in my code..Can you show me an example please of how to manipualte the view in ios without working with onPause?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a way to programmatically initiate these events as they are system events fired by Cordova. The only thing you can do is listen for them and run a function in response. Something like this:

```
function onDeviceReady() {
    document.addEventListener("pause", onPause, false);
}

function onPause() {
    // Handle the pause event

    if(device.platform ==='Android'){
        // do stuff
    }
}
```